# How to get the "Date" of an email?

Tags: c#, email, datetime, mailmessage

I create an application that gets email from mail server.
I use "System.Net.Mail.MailMessage" for receive email.
Now I want to get "Date and Time" of each email that ins in Inbox.

Comment: Be more specific if you can. DateTime from the html header? Or the date your mail client receives it?

Comment: I guess I want DateTime from the html header.For example in gmail, I want that DateTime that shows in each email.

Comment: Well I won't claim to explain anything that Micah already hasn't. Using the system.net.mail.mailmessage class you have access to all of that information you need in the Headers. Have a look at his answer and the link he's provided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will want to look at the emails headers here is some documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers.aspx

```
message.Headers["Date"];
```

Comment: This headers means to be just a string in rather specific format, is parsing it manually the best practice to get the date?

Comment: Yes this is going to come back as a string and then you will need to use datetime.parse

Comment: watch out - DateTime.Parse won't always be able to parse certain dates that may come back in headers : eg. "Tue, 20 Jun 2017 18:51:10 +0000 (UTC)"

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the MailMessageObject and found this:

```
  Headers=HeaderCollection(5) 
  {
    "Uid",
    "DateCreated",
    "DateReceived",
    "Date",
    "IsRead"
```

So that means you have a total of three options available to you. The output will be in string format.

```
message.Headers["DateCreated"];
message.Headers["DateReceived"];
message.Headers["Date"];
```